# getting an error about char* in using strcmp(char*,char*)

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I'm getting this error:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g translate.c support.c scanner.c -o translate
support.c: In function ‘translate’:
support.c:148:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ from incompatible pointer type     [enabled by default]
             compareNum = strcmp(dict[i], token);
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:29:0,
                 from support.c:1:
/usr/include/string.h:28:6: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 int  _EXFUN(strcmp,(const char *, const char *));
  ^
```

and here is the function translate()

```
int
translate(char* token, char** dict[], int dictLength)
{
    int i = 0;
    int compareNum;

    for(i=0;i<dictLength;i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            compareNum = strcmp(dict[i], token);
            ++i;
            if(compareNum == 1)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

return 0;

}
```

for some reason I'm passing in dict[i], which is an array of strings that I'm trying to compare each even element of the array to the string token but its saying its char**. I know the array is char** but wouldn't the element be char *?

Comment: char**[] is an array of char**, not a array of char*.

Comment: show your declaration of dict

Comment: @Pradheep he did, its an argument to the function

Comment: You do realise that when two strings are equal, `strcmp` returns 0, not 1, right?

Comment: oh my bad. I'll rewrite the if function

Comment: this is the main function that initializes it, creates an array with its name and fills it with tokens:

`
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int i;
    int count1;
    int count2;
    char **dictionary;
    char **message;

    if(argc != 3)
        {
        printf("need two arguments!\n");
        exit(-1);
        }

    count1 = countLines(argv[1]);
    count2 = countTokens(argv[2]);

    printf("there are %d tokens and strings in file 1\n", count1);

    dictionary = createArray(count1);

    readLines(argv[1], dictionary);
`

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

The `dict` argument is declared like so:

```
char** dict[]
```

So `dict[i]` is of type `char**`. Hence the error.

I guess that in order for us to offer further advice we'd need to have some details of the object that you supply as the `dict` argument when calling this function. Perhaps you simply need to change the declaration of the argument to be:

```
char* dict[]
```

One thing that I would recommend strongly would be to use `const` when declaring these parameters, to allow you to pass non-modifiable strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have `dict` parameter declared as:

```
char** dict[]
```

Which is  an array of `char**`.

This means `dict[index]` is a `char**`

Changing the parameter

```
char** dict[]
```

to

```
char* dict[]
```

should fix your problem